# SSRS 2012 and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is there any issue with SSRS 2012 i'm passing parameters to my report, when run it on the page it is not working work, but when removing the parameters it working fine is there any issue on ssrs 2012 please

```
  MyReportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote
    MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://jean-daniel/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESSADDD")
    ' Report Server URL
    MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Report Project2/Auction History"
    ' Report Name

    Dim params(0) As ReportParameter
    params(0) = New ReportParameter("SellerID", 201, False)
    MyReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(params)
    MyReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh()
    MyReportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = False
    MyReportViewer.ShowToolBar = False
```

Comment: Can you trace the value of params(0) on your report with a label?

Comment: i can't even see the report on the web form

Comment: There is a whole lot of info you are not seeing being logged at: <SERVER>\<SQL SSRS INSTALL FOLDER>\LogFiles